# PHP - Parse Facebook Post JSON

Tags: php, json, parsing, facebook-graph-api

I am really struggling with parsing JSON data from Facebook's Graph API. I am using `file_get_contents` and `json_decode` to decode the object

```
$json = file_get_contents($facebook_url);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
```

Here is some sample JSON:

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "place": {
        "id": "134972803193847",
        "name": "University of Southern California",
        "location": {
           "city": "Los Angeles",
           "country": "United States",
           "latitude": 34.021142052439,
           "longitude": -118.28519155575,
           "state": "CA",
           "street": "3551 Trousdale Pkwy",
           "zip": "90089"
        }
     },
     "picture": "https://fbcdn-vthumb-a.akamaihd.net/hvthumb-ak-xtf1/v/t15.0-10/xxxxxxxx",
     "id": "xxxxxxxxxx",
     "created_time": "2015-06-12T02:26:04+0000"
  },
  {
     "place": {
        "id": "74286767824",
        "name": "Los Angeles International Airport (LAX)",
        "location": {
           "city": "Los Angeles",
           "country": "United States",
           "latitude": 33.943998965589,
           "longitude": -118.402533192,
           "state": "CA",
           "street": "1 World Way",
           "zip": "90045"
        }
     },
     "picture": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/v/t1.0-9/xxxxxxx",
     "id": "xxxxxxxx12321",
     "created_time": "2015-06-06T22:57:49+0000"
  },
],
"paging": {
  "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/wfefwfwefwe",
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/fweewfwef"
}
}
```

I have tried various solutions but `echo` keeps printing "Array"

I am trying to get a few fields for each post such as id, name, city, country, latitude, longitude, state, created_time, picture.

I tried this and it just printed "Array" a bunch of times. I know this is a simple JSON parsing/PHP issue.

```
foreach($obj['data'] as $chunk) {
  foreach($chunk['place'] as $place) {      
    $fbid   = $place['id'];
    $name = $place['name'];
    $location = $place['location'];
    $city = $location['city'];
    $country = $location['country'];
    $latitude = $location['latitude'];
    $longitude = $location['longitude'];
    $state = $location['state'];
    $tuple = array($fbid, $name, $city, $country, $latitude, $longitude, $state);
    echo $tuple . "\n";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo` prints `Array()` because you are casting an array to a string.

To print the array in a human-readable format use `print_r($obj);` then, to print the id for the first place for example, use `echo $obj['data'][0]['place']['id'];` or loop through all the places and print each id use

```
foreach ($obj['data'] as $a) {
    echo $a['place']['id'];
}
```

You can find more info about print_r on the PHP manual pages. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 2):

[Live Demo](https://eval.in/382953)

Your output is an object. So you can not access an object by `[`.

Try this:

```
foreach($obj->data as $chunk) {

    $fbid   = $chunk->place->id;
    $name = $chunk->place->name;
    $location = $chunk->place->location;
    $city = $location->city;
    $country = $location->country;
    $latitude = $location->latitude;
    $longitude = $location->longitude;
    $state = $location->state;
    $tuple = array($fbid, $name, $city, $country, $latitude, $longitude, $state);
    print_r( $tuple);

}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 134972803193847
    [1] => University of Southern California
    [2] => Los Angeles
    [3] => United States
    [4] => 34.021142052439
    [5] => -118.28519155575
    [6] => CA
)
Array
(
    [0] => 74286767824
    [1] => Los Angeles International Airport (LAX)
    [2] => Los Angeles
    [3] => United States
    [4] => 33.943998965589
    [5] => -118.402533192
    [6] => CA
)
```

When you need to print an array then you can not use `echo`. You should use [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) or [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Comment: This code gave me a warning that said I was passing an improper object to the foreach loop :/